# How do you make a 3D border in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, borders

I'm trying to recreate this effect with the slightly shaded 3D border. I'd love to create a template so that I can more easily showcase my websites in a good looking way.
[image: What I'm trying to do]

The closest that I've been able to come to this effect is by using Vanishing Point and creating some additional perspective, and adding a Satin effect over the image. However this seems to give me a more "rounded" look that doesn't quite get what I'm trying to do.
[image: Attempt]

Help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)